# iOS Closes web page opened by camera QR scan when quit

Tags: javascript, html, ios, camera, qr-code

iOS now have build in camera QR code scan feature WHICH IS VERY COOL,

Therefore, I built a QR code for my website.

The problem is, after scan the code and the page is open, if the user choose to close the page via push up the app, the page disappears completely therefore, people cannot find the page opened by QR scan.

After investigation, I discovered that after the page is open via iOS QR scan, it doesn't actually launch Safari browser instead it uses QR scan app. And this app does not save cookie, which leads to every time when the user scan the page, I don't know it is a new user or a return user.

Is there a way to fix these 2 issues from coding prospective?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep the page open, you can scan the QR code with the camera rather than the *QR scan app*. By doing so, you will be able to open the URL in the browser, which will not go away if you switch to another app and come back.